# Magento 2 - change value in admin order grid column

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, custom

I want to change value in admin order grid table in **"Grand Total (Base)"** column. Just add some value to it. I assume I need to create `sales_order_grid.xml` in my module and create block with `prepareDataSource()` function like when I adding new column to grid. But how to override the existing one?

So in original xml we have:

```
<column name="base_grand_total" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Grand Total (Base)</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Basically all I need is set my one class instead of `Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price`. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: check my answer, i did it directly with ui_component xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here what I did:

added to my di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price"
            type="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price" />
```

And in that Price.php file I override prepareDataSource function like this

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            $currencyCode = isset($item['base_currency_code']) ? $item['base_currency_code'] : null;
            if ($this->getData('name')=='base_grand_total') {
               $item[$this->getData('name')] += //whatever I want to add;
            }

            $item[$this->getData('name')] = $this->priceFormatter->format(
                $item[$this->getData('name')],
                false,
                null,
                null,
                $currencyCode
            );
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best way, but it worked

Comment: on my own, I think creating a new module and overriding as you did is the right way to do this

Comment: check my answer, i did it directly with ui_component xml.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could be useful for next users, instead of using `di.xml` i did it with ui component, just add to your custom module `\app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns">
        <column name="price" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

it is the magento price column config taked from `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_listing.xml` except **column component class** that is replaced with your custom class.

Now you could use your custom class (like accepted answer) `\app\code\Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Price`.