# Magento 2 Backend: Make orderable qty per source and salable quantity

Tags: magento2, backend

There's a way to make orderable "Quantity per source" and "Salable quantity" coloumns on backend product list?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some coding to do if you want to achieve this.

### Salable Quantity

This setting is configured in `vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns">
        <column name="salable_quantity"
                class="Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity"
                component="Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi/js/product/grid/cell/salable-quantity"
                sortOrder="77">
            <settings>
                <filter>false</filter>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
                <label translate="true">Salable Quantity</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

To change this, you'll need to create or extend a custom module to override the `sortable` setting. You may also need to create your own class to replace `\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SalableQuantity`, as this user suggested [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/204900/76310).

### Quantity per Source

This one's a bit trickier since the column appears to be configured in classes, not xml.

First, this value is set in the private function `getQuantityPerSourceMeta` of `Magento\InventoryCatalogAdminUi\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Listing\Modifier\QuantityPerSource`:

```
private function getQuantityPerSourceMeta(): array
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'sortOrder' => 76,
                        'filter' => false,
                        'sortable' => false,
                        'label' => __('Quantity per Source'),
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Column::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi/js/product/grid/cell/quantity-per-source',
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

This function is called from the same class's `modifyMeta` function, the simplest solution would be to create a plugin for this class with an `afterModifyMeta` function in which you can modify the `sortable` value as you desire.

The other location you might need to handle is the (also private) function getQuantityPerSourceMeta in \Magento\InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\AddColumnQuantityPerSource`:

```
private function getQuantityPerSourceMeta(): array
    {
        $jsComponent = 'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi/js/form/element/grid-column-quantity-per-source';

        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'filter' => false,
                        'sortable' => false,
                        'label' => __('Quantity per Source'),
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'componentType' => Column::NAME,
                        'component' => $jsComponent,
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

This is called in this plugin class's `afterGetMeta` function. You may need either to create your own plugin with your own `afterGetMeta` function and ensure it runs after this core plugin, or else override this plugin so you can modify the meta directly.

Comment: Thanks for the post, this code works correctly on default stock. However i use a custom stock and i would to make ordinable my custom stock. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe! Can you provide any more information? Are you using a third-party extension for your custom stock? Can you provide any more information on your use case? The more detail the better.

Comment: I don't use any extensions for my custom stock